# Use pylint with sonarqube

Tags: python, gitlab, sonarqube, pylint, cicd

I apologize in advance.I have a task to create CI pipeline in Gitlab for projects on python language with results in SonarQube. I found some `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: image-registry/gitlab/python

before_script:
  - cd ..
  - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab/python-education/junior.git

stages:
  - PyLint

pylint:
  stage: PyLint
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - cp -R ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/* junior/project
    - cd junior && python3 run.py --monorepo
```

Is it possible to some code in script to output in SonarQube?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [third party issues](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/external-issues/) are supported with SonarQube. For PyLint, you can set `sonar.python.pylint.reportPath` in your sonar.properties file with the path of the report(s) for pylint. You must use `--output-format=parseable` argument to `pylint`.

When you run sonar scanner, it will collect the report(s) and send it to SonarQube.

Comment: if I set `sonar.python.pylint.reportPath=pylint-report.txt` where this file will create? And where I should use ` --output-format=parseable` command